# Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light error in android studio could not be resolved

Tags: android, sdk

Since android has updated the compile SDK version to API 27+ (Android API 27, Android P preview), I face [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FTyU.png).

The original problem was the `?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius` but I resolved it by updating my compile sdk version but after that this problem started and I cannot use `android:attr/` attribute.